# Was there ever a reason for why becoming a super saiyan became easy for the trunks and goten?

Tags: dragon-ball

Related to [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3075/when-does-one-become-a-super-saiyan), but I would like to know specifically for (young, not future) trunks and goten, how they managed to become super saiyans at such a young age - the others all went through a stressful emotional event that pushed them over the edge, yet while these two were growing up, I can't imagine them going through anything similar - there was no villain at the time.

[image: http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110328012834/dragonballaffanon/images/b/b5/Supersaiyan.jpg]

Comment: I personally consider it a plot hole.  I haven't seen any strong explanations for it yet(for the record, the explanation in the already existing answer to this question is not a very strong one)

Comment: Vegeta in DBZ calls it the super saiyan bargain sale, Gotenks and Trunk were born after Vegeta and Goku ascended even past the super saiyan stage.

Comment: To begin with super saiyan was a legend till goku first obtained it. From there we see vegeta train harder and finally he him self obtains the super saiyan. Even for gohan it was suoer hard. But when it came to goten and trunks its totally different as they weren't experimenting like vegeta or trying hard as gohan. The learning process had been shorten as main key to unlock this power was discovered and perfected by parents and grandparents. and may be due to gentic manipulation plays role here. I wont say this is a definite answer, rather a speculation and assumption to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The mixture of races is the answer. Gohan also become very young, but had more difficulties to release its power.

In the anime it is said that Goten and Trunks had fighting each other for fun, it probably gave them the skills needed to become.