# Are half-blooded Saiyans stronger than pure-blooded Saiyans?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-series

I'm wondering if half-blooded Saiyans are stronger than pure-blooded Super Saiyans? Like how half-blooded vampires are stronger than pure-blooded vampires.

Comment: out of curiosity, what was your source for stating that dhampir are stronger than vampires?

Comment: Like blade from marvel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-did-goten-and-trunks-become-super-saiyan-so-easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**According to Wikia**

1. The offspring generally possesses the strength of the Saiyans and develops abilities far more easily than Earthlings.
2. Hybrid Saiyans possess the potential to become Super Saiyans but it is unclear how many generations can separate a hybrid  from their Saiyan ancestor before the transformation becomes impossible.
3. It is unclear if these hybrids possess a naturally greater potential than their Saiyan parents. Gohan repeatedly demonstrated a hidden power that, when harnessed, made him more powerful than even Goku or Vegeta, and when he and Goku trained to battle Cell.
4. It is unclear if Hybrid Saiyans may become Super Saiyan faster than pure-blooded Saiyans. Gohan become Super Saiyan at  the age of 11 (9 in the manga). Trunks and Goten were able to make the transformation to Super Saiyan at a far younger age than their fathers, at the age of 8 and 7 respectively.
5. Further, it is unknown if quarter Saiyans, such as Pan, have a lesser potential than half Saiyans or pure-blooded Saiyans. Most importantly, Pan doesn't transform into Super Saiyan, or it's simply because it is harder to transform for females.

**According to my knowledge**

1. In the series, either Goku, Gohan or Future Trunks said that half-blooded Saiyans can transform into Super Saiyan earlier than pure-blooded Saiyans because they possess the Earthling's rich *emotions* and *feelings*. Since turning into Super Saiyan requires to be highly emotional, this makes half-blooded Saiyans transform at a very young age.
2. I don't think it's because half-blooded, so it's weaker than pure-blooded. For example, Goku passes down his ascendant gene to Gohan, so Gohan has the *potential* to surpass Goku. It takes training. In Cell Game Saga, Gohan trains in Hyperbolic Time Chamber together with Goku, and he ultimately surpasses Goku. If he trained non-stop like Goku, he might have become Super Saiyan God.
3. Obviously, the more generations, the lesser the Saiyan's blood in their body. I don't know if that works with Saiyans, but in real life it does. In the 10th generation, or roughly 300 years later, the Hybrid Saiyans will become 1/1024 Saiyan-1023/1024 Human. As you can see, Hybrid Saiyans are not likely to transform into Super Saiyan, but they still possess enhanced strength.
4. Maybe someday either Bulma or Bulla invents a device that can release the hidden potential, making it easier to turn into Super Saiyan.

Comment: This is a very good answer. However, point 4 regarding it being harder for females to transform to Super Saiyan is inaccurate because we see Caulfla and Kale(Full blooded Saiyans, however females), easily able to do it. Also I would like to add that Vegeta stated Gohan had the highest latent ability out of all the fighters he new in Universe 7.(However, I believe it is freiza) yet Gohan's potential is even superior to Kid Trunks and Goten, despite the 3 of them being Half Saiyans.

Answer (score 1):

Vegeta in Dragon Ball Z says

> Vegeta: “At any rate, the battle power of Kakarot’s son is unusually
>   high, even by the standards of Saiyan children.” Nappa: “Maybe his
>   reading was wrong.” Vegeta: “No, it wasn’t wrong. Raditz really took a
>   large amount of damage from that brat’s attack. It seems that mixing
>   Saiyan and Earthling blood begets a powerful hybrid.”

Comment: In which chapter or episode is that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, without a doubt half blood Saiyans are stronger than full blood Saiyans because even Goku had to admit that Gohan was stronger than him and Vegeta in *Dragon Ball Super*.

Not to mention half blood Saiyans have more feeling which can lead to a greater or earlier chance of turning Super Saiyan that is exactly why SSJ Rage Trunks beat merged Zamasu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Half blooded saiyans are stronger but there's a limit. If you have read manga and heard the interviews of Akira Toriyama, then you may come to know that half blooded saiyans can't go to the extreme levels like SS God because their durability is lower than full blooded saiyans (as for the human gene). And also they are also not interested in fighting or doing better than they are, only fights when needed. Instead of it they usually pay more attention to their family.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. This looks like a starting point for a good answer, could you [edit] and provide some sources/references to the manga and interviews?